# Triple DES encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, des

Please note that the issue I am having here is with the key *size*. At first, based on the comments included in the below code, I figured that my key needed to be 24 bytes (192 bits). This didn't work so I gave 16, 32, and 8 byte keys a shot - nothing seems to be working. By "not working" I mean that after my text has been encrypted and decrypted it does not hold the same value as my original text.

#### Example:

**Original Text:** `'Example test this should work '`

**Encrypted Text:** ¸`¹pÕô6`

**Decrypted Text:** `'Example '`

Here are the two functions I am using (Encrypt / Decrypt functions). Also I will include how I am calling each function.

```
        // 168-bit (three-key) 3DES (Triple-DES) encrypt a single 8-byte block (ECB mode)
        // plain-text should be 8-bytes, key should be 24 bytes.
        public byte[] TripleDesEncryptOneBlock(byte[] plainText, byte[] key)
        {
            // Create a new 3DES key.
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            // Set the KeySize = 192 for 168-bit DES encryption.
            // The msb of each byte is a parity bit, so the key length is actually 168 bits.

            des.KeySize = 192;
            des.Key = key;
            des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            ICryptoTransform ic = des.CreateEncryptor();

            byte[] enc = ic.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, 8);

            return enc;
        }

        public byte[] TripleDesDecryptBlock(byte[] plainText, byte[] key)
        {
            // Create a new 3DES key.
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            // Set the KeySize = 192 for 168-bit DES encryption.
            // The msb of each byte is a parity bit, so the key length is actually 168 bits.
            des.KeySize = 192;
            des.Key = key;
            des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            ICryptoTransform ic = des.CreateDecryptor();

            byte[] dec = ic.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, 8);

            return dec;
        }

// Encrypt Text
textBox5.Text = ByteToString(TripleDesEncryptOneBlock(StringToByte(textBox5.Text), StringToByte("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 2 ")));

// Decrypt Text
textBox5.Text = ByteToString(TripleDesDecryptBlock(StringToByte(textBox5.Text), StringToByte("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 2 ")));
```

Thank you for any help,

Evan

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but the CipherMode.ECB strikes me as funny given the website... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-isnt-my-encryption-encrypting.html

Comment: What are you getting at here ... ?

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the name of the function you're using:  `TripleDesEncryptOneBlock`

This method only encrypts one block of the input string (8 bytes or 64 bits).  To encrypt the entire string you need to chain multiple calls to this method.

Comment: It seems very odd that I'd have to call this method multiple times. Is there some way to modify this code so that I don't need to do this?

Comment: The purpose is so you can implement different chaining methods such as CBC or CFB.

Comment: What is the propery way to call this function in blocks of 8? Could you give me a hand with this? Should I just split the data into 8 byte pieces and call it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`byte[] enc = ic.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);`

I hope it will encrypt/decrypt your whole string. Also you will need not to call this method multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
byte[] dec = ic.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, 8);
                                                  ^
```

you only encode the first 8 characters of your array So when you decode, there are only those 8 characters to decode, which results in `'Example '`.

if you want to encode all your text, you have to increase that value. But be carefull, if you use `PaddingMode.None` it will fail if the lenght of the array-to-be-encoded is not a multiple of 8.

I added some padding to my text like this:

```cs
int length = plainText.Length / 8;
if(plainText.Length%8 > 0)
{
    length++;
}
byte[] paddedText = new byte[length * 8];
plainText.CopyTo(paddedText, 0);
byte[] enc = ic.TransformFinalBlock(paddedText, 0, length * 8);
```