# How to get a unique ID for a string and the string from this ID with C#?

Tags: c#

I have this name:

```
string name = "Centos 64 bit";
```

I want to generate a 168-bit (or whatever is feasible) uid from this name and to be able to get the name from this id vice versa
.
I tried this one **GetHashCode()** without success.

Result would be something like:

Centos 64 bit (=) 91C47A57-E605-4902-894B-74E791F37C1F

Comment: What exactly didn't work with GetHashCode? "Without success" is not an adequate problem description. Of course, it isn't guaranteed to return a 168-bit UID. If you need something that specific, you'll have to write the code yourself. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924997/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-hashcode-for-a-string

Comment: But what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062391/decrypt-hash-string-from-string-gethashcode ?

Comment: It is not possible. Calculating hash (any) by shortcut function is irreversable.

Comment: hashcode is know for being not decryptable, i don't know if i've understood but you can't recreate the string from the hashcode

Comment: hashing is a one-way function. you can go string->hash easily, but hash->string is theoretically impossible.

Comment: @nopeflow is there another way??

Comment: you can create your own cryptable method and decrtyptable method...if the security is not your primary objective

Comment: The only way is to encrypt that text and later decrypt it again. Hash is not possible, onle one way.

Comment: @Lorenzo give me some more help

Comment: for istance convert all the letter with their ascii code

Comment: @GiannisGrivas you need to encrypt it or create own map function (fe. based on ASCII code like someone mentioned before). But then - you cannot ensure that result will always be of 168-bit length.

Comment: You should search a SO first.
How about this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990286/triple-des-encryption

Comment: Just covert your string to bytes and pad it to a length of 21 bytes. If you use ASCII, your string will be limited to 21 characters.

Is there a reason this won't work?

Comment: just use `name = name;` ...it's unique *and* it can easily be reversed by using the exact same method

Comment: @MikeMarynowski maybe this could work.

Comment: Encryption won't really work...I don't know of any encryption function that will convert a string of that length to only 21 bytes. If you don't need to be secretive with your ID then just convert to ASCII and pad it. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Comment: Maybe you just want to obfuscate the string: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET

Simply, you can get the ascii values of each character and add 256/2 to it to make it a new character and subtract to undo.

Comment: @musefan I need an id from this string.I am asking if I can do it someway. Maybe MikeMarynowski caught it

Comment: Please explain the close requests?? I am trying to find a solution here.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas: Well it's unique, so it will work just fine as an ID.... why is it important for it to be transformed?

Comment: could also be helpful if you mention possible lengths of input strings

Comment: I think (I didn't vote to close) the request are because you really don't know what you want.

Comment: can't you have a dictionary which stores strings and the uids they were mapped to ? this way you can easily go back from uid to string

Comment: @musefan the reason I want something like that is quite complex. I just want to know if it feasible

Comment: @Dan Andrews I clearly know what I want.I think the description is very clear.

Comment: There are lots of reasons you might want this. One off the top of my head being that you are working with an existing database that you can't modify which has a 168 bit UID field that you want to double as a unique name string.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas clearly based on the extended discussion in the comments, you may know what you want, but not what you need.  I was just guess why you had so many VTC - maybe I'm wrong.  <- See what I did there?  I'm okay with being wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I would recommend is to use a hash function and something like a dictionary. So, get a hash - say SHA256 - of your input string and truncate it to 168 bytes.

Now, to go back from a uid to original string, you would need to have a dictionary which stores pairs like (input_string, string_uid). input_string is original string and string_uid is the uid generated for input_string using method from first paragraph.

Using this dictionary you can easily go back to original input string using string_uid.

This is one way - of course in case, you are allowed to store mappings between string and uid.

---

The hash normally gives you result as byte array. Converting this byte array to string is a separate step.

For example if you have 10 bytes representing integers in the range [0, 255], converting it to string if you encode the byte array as hex string, will take 20 bytes.

So the next question is do you want the length of the uid as string to be 21 bytes?

Because this will mean the hash output must be somewhere like 10 bytes, this will poorly reflect on collision resistance of the output.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas You should be able to code it yourself, you just need (1) Pass a string to some hash function (2) Extract only first 21 bytes (3) Store in a dictionary a string and its hash

Comment: it seems feasible. I 'll try it.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas But as I noted you will need  a dictionary which remembers which string was mapped to which uid

Comment: This won't let you grab a UID from the database and convert it back to a name after your program closes and reopens.

Comment: Yes op will need to persist dictionary too and keep it confidential if privacy of uid and strings matters

Answer (score 0):

Here you go sir:

```
    public byte[] GetUID(string name)
    {            
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);

        if (bytes.Length > 21)
            throw new ArgumentException("Value is too long to be used as an ID");

        var uid = new byte[21];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, uid, 0, bytes.Length);

        return bytes;
    }

    public string GetName(byte[] UID)
    {
        int length = UID.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < UID.Length; i++)
        {
            if (UID[i] == 0)
            {
                length = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(UID, 0, length);
    }
```

Caveats: it works for strings up to 21 characters in length that only use ASCII characters (no Unicode support) and it doesn't encrypt the string in any way, but I believe it meets your requirements.

Comment: Sorry made a correction, forgot to break out of the loop.

Comment: thats not fair - you limit to names that can fit :-)

Comment: Yeah also this is basically doing nothing :) just storing byte representation of string? :)

Comment: Yes, which he said should work. He wants to get a 168 bit value that can be converted back to the string. This achieves that.

Comment: It has to fit, he wants it to go two ways. If it doesn't fit then how will you convert it back to the name?

Comment: Your solution will work if he keeps a dictionary mapping back in local memory...but if he needs to get this out of a database later and convert it to a name then it won't work. I assumed this was the case, otherwise why the restriction of a 168 bit UID?

Comment: This solution also doesnt give privacy if op needs it

Comment: Did he say he needs it?

Comment: Updated my answer with caveats for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is not achievable. You need to store a lookup table of hash to name. Since you dont give more details of yr system it hard to say if that has to be persistent or in memory. If in memory just use a dictionary of string->string

Comment: mike marynowski solution only works cos he limits the name scope, maybe that is enough for you

Comment: Look @pm100 I want to convert it and afterall store it on a sql database. Then , I want to take that uid and reverse it back to the name.

Comment: I think mike marynowski caught it in the first place. I am asking for something very clear I think.isn't it?